# Golang: Opposite of Append to remove data

Tags: go, append

Here's the how I append data to struct:

```
user.Things = append(user.Things, item.Id)
```

Now, how can I remove `item.id` from `user.Things`? Seems like there's no method like `delete`, `remove`, or similar.

For example, this didn't work:

```
user.Things = append(user.Things[:item.id], user.Things[:item.id + 1:])
```

Comment: you have an extra colon in your slice expression: should be `append(user.Things[:item.id], user.Things[item.id+1:])`

Comment: @JimB, thank you, it worked!

Comment: @JimB you could have answer that :D

Comment: @GujaratSantana, simple typos are off topic, will usually be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page [Slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) gives a good overview about operations on slices.

There is also a few ways to delete an elements a slice: cutting, deleting or deleting without preserving order.

In your case, it seems you just had a typo (an extra colon):

`user.Things = append(user.Things[:item.id], user.Things[item.id + 1:])`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just assign to your slice the same slice but one item shorter:

user.Things = user.Things[:len(user.Things)-1]